# The connection was rejected in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, rest-client

i'm a newbie in vs code and get this error when I try to POST, can anyone please tell me where did I wrong? [image]

I've tried to get off my firewall but still nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Its long time but maybe someone else also get this error.
I am also newbie and in my case problem was that, I used https instead of http on localhost (host and app is defined in settings.json if someone wonder)

```
GET https://{{host}}/{{app}}
```

correct code is like this

```
GET http://{{host}}/{{app}}
```